# fs2 evalFold? Fold by evaluating effects?

Tags: stream, fold, fs2, cats-effect

I would like to be able to evaluate every step while folding an fs2 stream.

```scala
Stream.iterable[F, Int](List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
  .evalFold(0){ case (acc, e) => logger.info(acc + e).as(acc + e) }
```

Do you know a way to do this? Can you write up a helper function, made up of a combination of functions from `Stream`?

Assuming `logger.info()` is `Int => F[Unit]`

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on fs2 gitter that

- I could either use `evalScan(..).last`
- or I could write an `evalFold` by taking implementation of `evalScan` and adjusting it to only output at the end

[fs2 API Stream.scan](https://javadoc.io/static/co.fs2/fs2-core_2.13/2.4.6/fs2/Stream.html#scan%5BO2%5D(z:O2)(f:(O2,O)=%3EO2):fs2.Stream%5BF,O2%5D)